# Mongodb created replica set string showing exception

Tags: mongodb, creation, replicaset

I have got this issue while working on replica sets. Server is successfully turning on but after executing `rs.initiate()` and `rs.status` I am getting errors.

```
"info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
"errmsg" : "exception: bad --replSet config string format is: <setname>[host1>,<seedhost2>,...]",
"code" : 13093,
"ok" : 0
```

Comment: have you added the replica set members in the primaty node ?

Comment: yes I did i have started my all my servers

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well.  What happened was I configured the replica set in `/etc/mongo.conf`, went into the mongo client and executed `rs.initiate()`.  What I forgot to do was restart mongo!  A simple `sudo service mongod restart` fixed it.